Help in proving statements related with the gradient.
I'm given a differentiable function $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$, (i.e scalar field), and we define
$$ \langle grad \hspace{0.5mm} f(p), u \rangle = df_p(u) $$ for all $p \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and all $u \in \mathbb{R}^n_{p}$ (the tangent space), and I am asked to proof:

In the canonical basis $\lbrace e_i \rbrace$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$, the gradient is given by

$$ grad \hspace{0.5mm} f = \sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i} e_i  $$

The linear map $df_p: \mathbb{R}^n_p \to \mathbb{R}$ restricted to the unit sphere with center at $p$ reaches its maximum for $v= \frac{grad \hspace{0.5mm} f}{\lVert grad \hspace{0.5mm} \rVert}$

For 1 If we choose the standard basis for the tangent space $\mathbb{R}^n_p$ we get $\displaystyle grad \hspace{0.5mm} f = \sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i} e_i$, then it can be easily derived from the initial definition, by
$$ \langle grad \hspace{0.5mm} f, u \rangle = df_p(u) = \sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i} dx_i = \sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i} u_i   $$
(Here are my doubts for 1), what is meant by the standard basis in the tangent space, maybe the partial derivatives?, and, I can't see how this can be easily derived from the initial definition)
For 2, if we are restricted to the unit sphere $S^n$ with center at $p$, that means we are taking vectors $v \in \mathbb{R}^n_{p}$ such that $\lVert v \rVert =1$, in this "approach" we define $\langle grad \hspace{0.5mm} f(p), u \rangle = \lVert grad \hspace{0.5mm} f(p) \rVert \lVert v \rVert \text{cos} \hspace{0.5mm} \theta = \lVert grad \hspace{0.5mm} f(p) \rVert \text{cos} \hspace{0.5mm}  \theta$, and the maximum value of $\text{cos} \hspace{0.5mm} \theta$ is $1$, and this happens when $\theta = 0$. In here, I am stuck, any suggestion, or maybe if there is a better way to proof this part.
